# What the white part is on the ceiling in this tutorial?

Tags: drywall

there is a tutorial demonstrating HOW TO INSTALL DRYWALL ON A CEILING.

That guy [is putting a screw into the ceiling](https://youtu.be/xnarltDAUZQ?t=192).

[image]

Is the white part pointed out by red arrow drywall? If yes, where is paper. That guy said want "drywall screw to be flush with the paper"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drywall is made of gypsum surrounded with paper.  The paper is the front and back surface of the drywall.

Comment: So the screw is tightened so that the top of its head is flush with, or just slightly under, the surface of the drywall so that covering is easier.

Comment: I'd describe it as 'barely below the surface of the paper". (If you slide a taping knife across the screw and it clicks, it needs to be deeper.) And if you go too deep, just put in another screw a couple of inches away.